# Question about Neighborhoods from Alfhors

Tags: general-topology

In the passage by Alfhor's Complex Analysis, under Chapter 3 Compactness, states:
[image: Alfhors]

I am new to topology, but here's my understanding: If a neighborhood isn't "intersecting" or doesn't have a point belonging to $X$ we can ignore it, and if it does, we replace that neighborhood with $2\epsilon$-neighborhood so that the neighborhood now meets $X$. I also understand that finite covering is there to provide "definiteness" to the open covering of $X$. However, immediately a red flag arose.

**Question** This building of finite covers, and "filtering", saying "Yea " or "Nay" doesn't sit right. Is there a formalism or theorem that allows us to do in a sense this ambiguous "filtering" and the ability to replace a $\epsilon$-neighborhood with a $2\varepsilon$-neighborhood to achieve a finite sub-covering?

Comment: Please do not use images to convey critical information not otherwise contained in you post. [Here are the reasons why you should not do this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: Why are you suspicious of ignoring members of the cover that don't cover anything?

Comment: @MPW As I mentioned,  I am new to learning topology. And it seemed foreign to toss things Willy-Nilly, but as you put it like that, you make a good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely the definition of open covering compactness: $X$ is compact in this sense iff for every open covering, there exists a finite subcovering.

For metric spaces (and even under less strict assumptions about the topology), this is equivalent to the convergent subsequence definition of compactness.

The replacement of $\varepsilon$-neighborhoods with $2\varepsilon$-neighborhoods just guarantess the centers to be contained within $X$. The triangle inequality guarantees the existence of such replacement neighborhoods that still cover $X$. After replacement, the definition of compactness is used to reduce the amount of neighborhoods needed to finitely many.

Comment: Ah, I see, so it does add a sense of definiteness so to ensure all of $X$ the points are included we stretch by 2epsilon-neighborhood. And then with that, we are ensured we have all of $X$. Therefore allowing us to be able to select and reduce to finitely many neighborhoods. Correct?

Comment: The $\varepsilon$-neighborhoods already cover $X$ in your paragraph of the book. But depending on how you define the topology on a subspace for a metric space, you need the open balls to be centered in points of $X$ itself, not the ambient space. If viewed trough a general topology sense, this does not make much of a difference, but is slightly more abstract as a concept. The open balls correspond to a basis for the topology, if you want to read a bit further.

Comment: Good point, Thank you.